# SBTableAlert not working

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, automatic-ref-counting

First of all, I'm just starting on iPhone development. I'm trying to get an SBTableAlert working (see https://github.com/blommegard/SBTableAlert )

My initial setup is simple: I have a UIViewController with a button. On the button press, I do the following (as per the SBTableAlert example):

```
- (IBAction)myBtn_Press
{
    SBTableAlert *alert;
    alert   = [[SBTableAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Apple Style" cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" messageFormat:nil];
    [alert.view setTag:2];
    [alert setStyle:SBTableAlertStyleApple];

    MySecondViewController *myWGVC = [[MySecondViewController alloc] init];

    [alert setDelegate:myWGVC];
    [alert setDataSource:myWGVC];

    [alert show];
}
```

MySecondViewController is declared as:

```
@interface MySecondViewController : NSObject <SBTableAlertDelegate, SBTableAlertDataSource>
```

which means it will function as a delegate for the table view. I also include the following (pasted from the example):

```
@implementation MySecondViewController

#pragma mark - SBTableAlertDataSource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (tableAlert.view.tag == 0 || tableAlert.view.tag == 1) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    } else {
        // Note: SBTableAlertCell
        cell = [[SBTableAlertCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d", indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeSingleSelect)
        return 3;
    else
        return 10;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert {
    if (tableAlert.view.tag == 3)
        return 2;
    else
        return 1;
}

- (NSString *)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableAlert.view.tag == 3)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section Header %d", section];
    else
        return nil;
}

#pragma mark - SBTableAlertDelegate

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableAlert.type == SBTableAlertTypeMultipleSelct) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableAlert.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        else
            [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

            [tableAlert.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }
}

- (void)tableAlert:(SBTableAlert *)tableAlert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"Dismissed: %i", buttonIndex);
}
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
2013-04-25 00:13:35.389 MyTestProject[3386:c07] *** -[SBTableAlert tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x682ed80
```

however I have no idea how to trace this or debug it. It appears it could have something to do with ARC, since the demo project doesn't use it, but I can't pinpoint how to fix this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're not using ARC then you need an `[alert autorelease];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating properties with `strong` attribute in your main UIViewController subclass for both `alert` and `myWGVC` objects. They seem to be deallocated because of ARC before the alert is presented on screen since there are no strong references to the alert's delegate/datasource and the alert itself.